# On canonical bundle of some smooth surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface (over complex numbers) of general type (kodaira dimension 2). Then my questions are the following:

$(i)$ In general, Is there any relation between canonical bundle of $S$ and a smooth hyperplane section of $S$? (This is true in some cases, for example, hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^3$, but is there any relation with hyperplane section in other situations?)

The only thing that I know is $|nK_S|$ is an effective divisor for large enough $n$.

$(ii)$ Is $K_S$ necessarily ample?

$(iii)$ Is $K_S.D >0$, for any effective divisor $D$ on $S$?

Any remark from anyone is welcome

Comment: There might be good discussion to be had around this question if it were asked better. Right now this is question is really low on context and effort, which seems to be a pattern for you. Please improve your post.

Answer (score 4):

For the first question, if $H$ is a hyperplane section, $K_H= (K_S+H)_{|H}$.

For the second and third, let $S$ contain an exceptional divisor $E$ (for example, you could blow up a point on a surface). Then $K_S\cdot E=-1$.

Comment: that means in general $K_S$ and it's positive multiple can have negative intersection with an effective divisor and therefore not necessarily ample, right? For the first one I was trying to understand whether one can relate $D.H$ and $D.K_S$ for effective divisors $D$.